# Uses of UNION in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to cause a UNION to remove duplicate results only based off of certain columns?  From what I understand about the UNION is that it will only remove a duplicate row based off of all the fields in the duplicate results being identical.  For example: is it possible to alter the UNION in some way as to say "remove duplicate results, only when columns 1,4 & 5 are identical?"

Comment: Which values in columns other than 1,4, and 5 would you choose?  First?  Highest?  Average?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Comment: no, there isn't. What you can do is create a unique index on those columns and make it so it ignores duplicates

Answer (score 0):

There is only a `UNION` and a `UNION ALL`

You could use union to retrieve unique records and add a calculated field to achieve your need for uniqueness.

```
SELECT
    MyID,
    MyCalcValue=CASE WHEN MyID IN(1,3,4) THEN NEWID() ELSE NULL
FROM
  MyTable

UNION

SELECT
    MyID,
    MyCalcValue=CASE WHEN MyID IN(1,3,4) THEN NEWID() ELSE NULL
FROM
  MyTable2
```